# What's the meaning of SOD and SOX?

Tags: production-environment

We received an e-mail saying that there are SOD an SOX restriction for a Production environment. Are there common terms?

Comment: SOX might mean sarbannes-oxley if you're working in a finance company.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a specific programming problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likely meaning (without knowing more about the situation) is that SoD means [Separation of Duties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_duties) and that SOX refers to the [Sarbanes-Oxley Act](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarbanes%E2%80%93Oxley_Act).

Doing some searching I noticed that you are more likely to find information about them using the compete terms rather than the abbreviations.

Perhaps related: [Does SOX restrict access to QA environments or just production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548738/does-sox-restrict-access-to-qa-environments-or-just-production)

Answer (score 0):

It stands for 'Sulphur Oxides', and the term is more often used relating with environmental protection as combustion of fossil fuels cause the production of Sox(Sulphur Oxides) and the other might be Sulphur Dioxides.

Comment: This is true, but I'm not sure if StackOverflow is the right place for this question / answer (given the off-topicness of the question I think the answer is more than OK!)